# ModRewrite: Image in folder if isn't found

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to get a default image in a specific folder if the image file doesn't exist

so http://xyz.de/projekt/thumb/12_2323.jpg should check if http://xyz.de/somehidden/folderonwebspace/project/thumb/12_2323.jpg exists.
if not http://xyz.de/somehidden/folderonwebspace/project/thumb/default.png

```
RewriteRule ^projekt/thumb/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png){1}) /somehidden/folderonwebspace/project/thumb/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*$ /somehidden/folderonwebspace/project/thumb/default.png [L]
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Where is your htaccess file located?

Comment: htaccess is in root everytime i get an 403